# Exporting a dynamic Go struct into BigQuery's JSON field type

Tags: go, google-bigquery

As much as I want to use well-defined structures and schemas in BigQuery, I have a case now when I really need to export rows with a highly dynamic field into BigQuery.

This is the Go client I am using:
https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery

For brevity, here's my row struct in Go:

```
type Row struct { 
    Name     string    `bigquery:"name"`
    Count    int64     `bigquery:"count"`
    Metadata Metadata  `bigquery:"metadata"`
}
```

This `Metadata` struct is a slice of objects that have a set of nested fields. Some of those fields are unpredictable and this is why I cannot specify the schema explicitly and tag all the fields explicitly.

I have found the relatively new `bigquery.FieldType` `JSON` that is in theory supposed to work in these cases.

Having said that, I still get the error `field metadata is not a record type` when exporting my data to BQ.

This doesn't make a lot of sense because I decided to use this `JSON` field type in order to avoid specifying the schema for the `RECORD` type.

Another option would be to use the `auto detect` feature but it's only available when exporting data from a JSON file in a GCS bucket.

Is there a workaround in this case? Let me know if I should add more details to the question in the comments and I will do so.